# How do i search by name, key and value

Tags: redis

Example:

```
user_1st {
    productid_1 {
        'uname':'test',
        'email':'test@gmail.com',
        'product':'test'
    },
    productid_2 {
        'uname':'test2',
        'email':'test2@gmail.com',
        'product':'test2'
    }
}

user_2nd {
    productid_1 {
        'uname':'testing',
        'email':'testing@gmail.com',
        'product':'testing'
    },
    productid_2 {
        'uname':'testing2',
        'email':'testing2@gmail.com',
        'product':'testing2'
    }
}
```

I want to store key-value pairs into redis with name,

Any possible for able to filter the data based on productid_1, uname ?

Answer (score 0):

Redis contains data in key value format , You can use key to get data from database.

In my case I created one redis key in my business logic like this

```
"PCX.Core.Repositories.SubscriberRepository.SubscriberLastWeek_47"
```

On my business logic subscriberlastweek is method and 47 is customer id (parameter).

Created redis key=method name + parameter.

And value is "`[{"SubscriberRegisted":1,"RegistedDay":"Wednesday","Connection_Week":9}]"`

[image]

You can see redis data by RedisDesktopManager also.